# how to query embedded object in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

I have classes A, B

```
class A{
@Embedded
private B objB; 
}

@Embeddable 
class B{
Integer x;
Integer y;
float z;
}
```

Now I have a bunch of class A objs Set, I want to query the database, so that rows contain same x and y in Class B (z is not important in comparison in this case) should be selected, how do I achieve that?

It's like "In" in SQL, but since I am comparing embedded objects, how should I do with it ? Many thanks!!

Comment: Is your question, how to query all the `A` objects that have same value of `x` and `y`?

Comment: It doesn't look like `A` is an entity managed by Hibernate. It is missing `Entity` annotation and `Id` field. Is `A` an entity or plain java class? if `A` is an entity, you can try criteria query `session1.createCriteria(A.class, "a").add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("a.objB.x",1), Restrictions.eq("a.objB.y", 1))).list()` or hql `FROM A a where a.objB.x=:x and a.objB.y=:y").setParameter("x", 2).setParameter("y", 2).list()`

Answer (score 3):

Given the classes:

```
public class RandomEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Embedded
    private EmbeddableEntity embedded;
}
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class EmbeddableEntity {
    private Long valueA;
    private Long valueB;
}
```

You can query it like:

```
session.createQuery( "select a from RandomEntity a where a.embedded.valueA=:value" ).setParameter( "value", 1L ).list();

Hibernate: select randomenti0_.id as id1_2_, randomenti0_.valueA as valueA2_2_, randomenti0_.valueB as valueB3_2_ from RandomEntity randomenti0_ where randomenti0_.valueA=?
```

or:

```
session.createQuery( "select a from RandomEntity a where a.embedded.valueA in (:value)" ).setParameterList( "value", Arrays.asList( 1L, 2L ) ).list();

Hibernate: select randomenti0_.id as id1_2_, randomenti0_.valueA as valueA2_2_, randomenti0_.valueB as valueB3_2_ from RandomEntity randomenti0_ where randomenti0_.valueA in (?)
```